# How to overload the dot and bracket [] AND setItem() setters for sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to log the stack trace when an item is written to the session storage.

This is working fine for `sessionStorage.setItem('hello', 'world')` :

```
const ogSessionStorageSetItem = sessionStorage.setItem;

sessionStorage.setItem = async function(key, value) {
    console.log('Wrote', key);
    console.trace();

  ogSessionStorageSetItem.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

but it doesnt work when doing `sessionStorage.hello = 'world'` or `sessionStorage['hello'] = 'world'`.

I tried with a proxy :

```
const handler = {
    get: function(target, name) {
        console.log('get', name)
        console.trace()
        return target[name];
    },
    set:  function(target, name, value) {
        console.log('set', name)
        console.trace()
        target[name] = value;
    },

};

const proxy = new Proxy(sessionStorage, handler);

Object.defineProperty(window, "sessionStorage", {
    value: proxy,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    writable: false
});
```

It works for dot and [] but not for setItem.

How to get them both working ?

**Update 2:**

Tried solution (@Mr. Polywhirl), now I'm getting a side-effect : `sessionStorage.setItem = function...` thinks it has to save a key/value : setItem => function definition to the session storage.

```
const sessionStorageProxy = new Proxy(sessionStorage, {
  get(target, name, receiver) {
    console.log('get', name)
    console.log(receiver, target)
    console.trace()
    return Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
  },
  set(target, name, value, receiver) {
    console.log('set', name)
    console.trace()
    return Reflect.set(target, name, value, receiver);
  }
});


Object.defineProperty(window, "sessionStorage", {
    value: sessionStorageProxy,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    writable: false
});

const ogSessionStorageSetItem = sessionStorage.setItem;

// this below is acting like sessionStorage.super = 'cool'

sessionStorage.setItem = async function(key, value) {
  console.log('Wrote', key);
  console.trace();
  ogSessionStorageSetItem.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

[image]

Comment: The dot and bracket syntax does the same thing. Obviously calling the underlying property directly bypasses the setter function.

Comment: updated my code with a proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Mr Polywhirl, you can use `Proxy` to wrap your target object. with simple object it works great, but as soon as you start with complex object it will get messy pretty soon.

Anyways, based on your updated question, in your `get` handler, you are returning everything as a `value` but for value which is invokable (function), you need to either send another proxy with `apply` method configured in the proxy or invoke function on the original object and not proxy:

```
get(target, name, receiver) {
  const value = Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
  return typeof value === 'function' ?
    value.bind(target) :
    value;
}
```

Let's take a look at your code with the change applied:

```js
// we are overriding this before configuring proxy
// setting setItem afterwards will put this method on proxy itself and not on sessionStorage object
// override session storage
const ogSessionStorageSetItem = sessionStorage.setItem;
sessionStorage.setItem = async function(key, value) {
  console.log('Wrote', key);
  console.trace();
  ogSessionStorageSetItem.apply(this, arguments);
};

// create proxy
const sessionStorageProxy = new Proxy(sessionStorage, {
  get(target, name, receiver) {
    const value = Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
    return typeof value === 'function' ?
      value.bind(target) :
      value;
  },
  set(target, name, value, receiver) {
    if (name === 'setItem') {
      return false;
    }
    return Reflect.set(target, name, value, receiver);
  }
});


Object.defineProperty(window, "sessionStorage", {
  value: sessionStorageProxy,
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  writable: false
});

sessionStorage.key1 = "value1";
sessionStorage["key2"] = "value2";
sessionStorage.setItem('key3', 'value3');

console.log(sessionStorage.key1);
console.log(sessionStorage["key2"]);
console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("key3"));
```

You might find [this article](https://javascript.info/proxy) useful, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the `sessionStorage` inside of a `Proxy`. This allows you to hook into the setter.

```js
const sessionStorageProxy = new Proxy(window.sessionStorage, {
  get(target, name, reciever) {
    return Reflect.get(target, name, reciever);
  },
  set(target, name, value, receiver) {
    console.log('Wrote', name);
    return Reflect.set(target, name, value, receiver);
  }
});

sessionStorage.setItem = async function(key, value) {
  console.log('Wrote', key);
  console.trace();
  sessionStorageProxy.apply(this, arguments);
};

sessionStorage.setItem('hello', 'world');
console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('hello')); // world

sessionStorageProxy.hello = 'world2';
console.log(sessionStorageProxy.hello); // world2
```

Comment: thanks, i'm getting `sessionStorageProxy.apply is not a function`, how can I fix that?

Comment: @MichelDelpech I guess you could change it to `sessionStorage.apply`.

Comment: I have some weird side-effect. Now, sessionStorage.setItem thinks it has to register a new key/value pair : setItem => function definition haha (updated my answer)